# Routing Error - No route matches on AJAX call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, routes

I know there have been a lot of submissions about routing error, but even after going through many of those and looking at routing guide, I am not able to figure out my issue.

I have created a Ajax submission of form like -

```
$('#user_time_zone').live('change', function() {    
  $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
});
```

However, on the event, I am getting the Routing Error

```
No route matches '/user/time_zone'
```

My routes as such shows

```
user_time_zone POST   /user/time_zone(.:format)           {:controller=>"user", :action=>"time_zone"}
```

In routes file I have entry like -

```
match 'user/time_zone' => 'user#time_zone', :via => [:post]
```

What might I be doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you send a form with method `GET`
or
There is hidden field in form `_method=put`

Can you post request log from development.log and view with form?

Comment: In fact there is a hidden field in form _method=put.  That is generated by Rails code. I have declared form as - form_for(@user, :url => user_time_zone_path, :method => :post, :remote => true) do |f|   . How do I remove that. Maybe I am doing something wrong here. The generated form has a CSS class edit_user  . I am using Devise as well, so that is also adding some /user/* type routes.

Comment: Update: I have changed the HTTP method to PUT in routes via match 'user/time_zone' => 'user#time_zone', :via => [:put] and it seems to work. Thanks

Comment: I have no idea why manually putting the hidden div worked for me. Perhaps ajax loading a form builder partial messes things up. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
rake routes
```

and see all your routes are captured,

and if you could paste your routes, we might be able to help you

thanks and regards

sameera

Comment: Not able to post complete routes file, due to length, but have given teh relevant route taken from rake routes in original mail. I am using devise though is also adding some /user/* type routes, but they are below this route spec